# How Gunicorn forward request to flask

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

Can anyone describe the process of how `Gunicorn` forward the request to `Flask` `internally`?

It would be great if someone explains each and every step involved in the process from receiving the request by Gunicorn to forwarding it to Flask and the reverse way.

Please keep in mind while explaining that I am a newbee in this area.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gunicorn and Flask talks through [WSGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface), which has two sides: server side and the application side.

on the application(framework) side, we need to provide a callable, the simplest example:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return ['Hello World']
```

the server will call this application and providing environment information and a callback function which is used to indicate start of a response. when the server get the response, it will return it to browser.

so, for gunicorn and flask:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

when you do this, you've actually got an WSGI compatible application, `app` is a callable:

```
class Flask(object):
    ...

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        """Shortcut for :attr:`wsgi_app`."""
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

[source](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L1976)
```

and when you run `gunicorn app:app`, you're telling gunicorn where to load your application, [source](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py#L52)

when a request comes, gunicorn parses it, construct a dict `environ`, which is defined [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#environ-variables), contains information like `REQUEST_METHOD`, `QUERY_STRING` etc, then call the application(a Flask object!) with it: `app(environ, start_repsonse)` [source](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/workers/sync.py#L171), `start_repsonse` is a callback in Gunicorn to get the reponse status and headers,  and the return value of the `app` call will be send as response body.

Comment: What's the difference between calling app.run() and calling flask application using Gunicorn?

Comment: `app.run()` will run the app with the built in wsgi server of flask, which is for development purpose and performs poorly under high load. while gunicorn is highly optimized for performance

Comment: gunicorn python_file:app will tell gunicorn to where to load your application. What does it mean? Can you explain it little further?

Comment: gunicorn needs to import your application (the callable) first, so `gunicorn python_file:app` tells gunicorn that it can import your application from `python_file.app`

Comment: you can think it as gunicorn performing `from python_file import app`

Comment: What will happen if we are running Gunicorn with 2 workers and 4 threads? Will each thread have seperate instance of app?

Comment: @neel I think they will share the same instance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105795/discussion-between-wong2-and-neel).